# Saving sql query that contains arabic into a cell

Tags: sql-server

```
  declare @val nvarchar(max),@H_ARABIC nvarchar(max)
  select @val = 'select [settings_key] as  N''اسم''  from [settings]'
  set @H_ARABIC= @val;
  print @H_ARABIC
```

It is showing results as
      `select [settings_key] as  N'???'  from [application_setting]` but how can I get this result
    `select [settings_key] as  N'اسم'  from [application_setting]` I have tried many ways by changing the quotation mark but no use. Pls help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefix your string literal with `N`.

```
declare @val nvarchar(max),@H_ARABIC nvarchar(max)
  select @val = N'select [settings_key] as  N''اسم''  from [settings]'
  set @H_ARABIC= @val;
  print @H_ARABIC
```

Comment: hoooo... Mikeal Eriksson u saved me...!